# When plotting perceptron dataset using plotpv, the plot doesn't categorize the legends, but just repeats for all target data

Tags: matlab

I'm using 2X92 Input data and 1X92 target data and plotting the dataset using plotpv. The target data values are either 0 or 1. The plot generated with different marker for 0 and 1 of target data, but the legends are not set right. Both legends show the same marker for zero.

```
plotpv(P, T);
legend('A','B');
```

[image]

When I use the following, the system shows all 92 target data as legends. Not the marker type.

```
legend();
```

[image]

How to fix this to show the legends to show the marker types only?